# Why are different colors appearing for circles plotted with the same function and input values?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to create a Paint application with adjustable colors and brush radius using trackbars. I am using mouse events to differentiate between dragging and simply moving the mouse.

The code runs, however, when I am trying to draw on the image window, there are 2 unwanted behaviors:

- different colors based on whether the circle was created using a single mouse click or using mouse dragging
- different color towards upper edge of the image

How to fix this?

This is one of the OpenCV exercises: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_trackbar/py_trackbar.html#trackbar

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
drawing = False
def nothing(x):
    pass

# Create a black image, a window
img = np.zeros((768,1024,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')

# create trackbars for color change
cv2.createTrackbar('R','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('G','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('B','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('W','image',0,50,nothing)

def draw_brush(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global drawing, b, g, r, w
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),w,(b,g,r),-1)
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            a, b = x, y
            if a!=x & b!=y:
                cv2.circle(img,(x,y),w,(b,g,r),-1)
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
# Create a window and bind the function to window
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_brush)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

    # get current positions of four trackbars
    r = cv2.getTrackbarPos('R','image')
    g = cv2.getTrackbarPos('G','image')
    b = cv2.getTrackbarPos('B','image')
    w = cv2.getTrackbarPos('W','image')

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here

```
a, b = x, y
if a!=x & b!=y:
    cv2.circle(img,(x,y),w,(b,g,r),-1)
```

You use two variables "b". One as a coordinate value and one as a blue color value. So your blue color value gets value of "y" coordinate there. Use different variable name for "b" coordinate variable.

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. Once I used different variable names, the issue got fixed. Thanks for your help! :)